# Defining function is not working

Tags: command-line, bash, functions

I want to define this function:

```
displayInfo (){ echo "Hi";cal;date }
```

But after pressing enter, this is what I see:

```
>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're defining a function on a single line, you need a `;` to signify the end of the commands:

```
displayInfo (){ echo "Hi";cal;date; }
```

Alternatively, you can do it on multiple lines:

```
displayInfo (){ 
    echo "Hi"
    cal
    date
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a semicolon after "date":

```
displayInfo (){ echo "Hi";cal;date; }
```

In your code the bash interpreter fails to find the end of the function and prompts you to continue.